# How to read this tcpdump man page?

Tags: man, options

I am trying to use the tcpdump command in a project and I have some difficulties understanding the help page.

```
SYNOPSIS
   tcpdump [ -AbdDefhgHIJKlLnNoOpPqRStuUvxX ] [ -B buffer_size ] [ -c
   count ]
           [ -C file_size ] [ -G rotate_seconds ] [ -F file ]
           [ -i interface ] [ -j tstamp_type ] [ -k (metadata_arg) ]
           [ -m module ] [ -M secret ]
           [ -r file ] [ -s snaplen ] [ -T type ] [ -w file ]
           [ -W filecount ]
           [ -E spi@ipaddr algo:secret,...  ]
           [ -y datalinktype ] [ -z postrotate-command ] [ -Z user ]
           [ -Q packet-metadata-filter ]
           [ expression ]
```

First, what is this "[ -AbdDefhgHIJKlLnNoOpPqRStuUvxX ]" at the top ? What is the meaning of that ?
I also see a lot of people on the internet doing crazy things with this command, for example `tcpdmp -nnvvXSs 1514` ... what is that -nnvvXSs, and how can we know this can be used ?

I see codes examples that according to me does not correspond to the man page, I just don't get how to read, how to understand this help file.

Anybody tell me how to read this and understand it ?

Comment: Type 'man man' to learn how to read man pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By convention, the brackets indicate something that is optional. So you can run `tcpdump`, or `tcpdump -c 3 -i eth0`, or `tcpdump -c 3 -r /path/to/file`, etc. Also, unless explicitly indicated, options can be used in any order, so you can run `tcp -i eth0 -c 3`, etc.

Most commands allow options to be clustered when they use a single letter. For example, `tcpdump -AX` is equivalent to `tcpdump -A -X`. The manual groups all options that don't take arguments to make the presentation shorter: `[ -Abd ]` would be a shortcut for `[ -A ] [ -b ] [ -d ]`, etc.

The synopsis is just a summary. Read the “description” or “options” section to see what each option does and what the word after each option can be replaced with.

For example, `tcpdmp -nnvvXSs 1514` is a shorter equivalent of `tcpdump -n -n -v -v -X -s -s 1514`, and means:

- `-n`: don't do name resolution. Repeating this option has no additional effect.
- `-v`: causes tcpdump to print out more stuff. Repeating this option causes it to print even more stuff.
- `-X` adds a dump of the content of each packet to the output.
- `-S` causes absolute TCP sequence numbers to be printed.
- `-s 1514` causes only the first 1514 bytes of each packet to be captured.

Answer (score 1):

you can check man pages by scroll down to get more details about options

```
root@ubuntu:~# man tcpdump
```

to search for any keyword type /keyword then enter

Below are most common options you can use with tcpdump .

- -i any : Listen on all interfaces just to see if you’re seeing any traffic.
- -i eth0 : Listen on the eth0 interface.
- -D : Show the list of available interfaces
- -n : Don’t resolve hostnames.
- -nn : Don’t resolve hostnames or port names.
- -q : Be less verbose (more quiet) with your output.
- -X : Show the packet’s contents in both hex and ASCII.
- -XX : Same as -X, but also shows the ethernet header.
- -v, -vv, -vvv : Increase the amount of packet information you get back.
- -c : Only get x number of packets and then stop. icmp : Only get ICMP packets.
- -s : Define the snaplength (size) of the capture in bytes. Use -s0 to get everything, unless you are intentionally capturing less.
- -S : Print absolute sequence numbers.
- -e : Get the ethernet header as well.
- -q : Show less protocol information.
- -E : Decrypt IPSEC traffic by providing an encryption key.

you can check online resources if you're newbie to Tcpdump fee Free to check below .

https://danielmiessler.com/study/tcpdump/

http://packetpushers.net/masterclass-tcpdump-expressions/

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer sameh Ammar. I know that I can scroll down and I have read a good part of these keywords, but I still can not understand how things like this :  `-nnvvXSs` are possible. How can we know that we can gather keywords like that, and what is the meaning of such an expression ?

Comment: you can use more than one flag to increase or decrease information you want from Tcpdump output . let's  check this -nnvvXSs .

-nn : Don’t resolve hostnames or port names.
-X :Show the packet’s contents in both hex and ASCII.
--s : Define the snaplength (size) of the capture in bytes. Use -s0 to get everything, unless you are intentionally capturing less.
-S : Print absolute sequence numbers.

so final should be : -nnvvXSs

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I *may* start to understand. Tell me if I am right.

I tried this on my terminal `sudo tcpdump -nnvvXeB 1024 host 10.11.204.15`

So if I understand well, 
`-nnvvXeB 1024` is the same that 
`-nn -vv -X -e -B 1024` witch is the same that
`-B 1024 -nn -X -e -vv` witch is the same that
`-B 1024 -nnXevv`

Are they others "swapping" I can do with this command ?

In the man page there are different categories "NAME" "SYNOPSIS" "DESCRIPTION" "OPTIONS" "OUTPUT FORMAT" etc...
If I understand right, the commands in "SYNOPSIS" are all command that need to be followed by arguments (for example -F need to be followed by a file name, -i by the name of an interface etc..), whereas things listed in "OPTIONS" are just single letters that can be added without argument.

Am I right ?
Thanks