# How do you parse `lvrename [-A|--autobackup {y|n}] [-d|--debug] [-h|--help] [-t|--test] [-v|--verbose] [--version] [-f|--force] [--noudevsync]

Tags: lvm

Can someone clarify this piece of gibberish:

```
lvrename [-A|--autobackup {y|n}] [-d|--debug] 
[-h|--help] [-t|--test] [-v|--verbose] [--version] [-f|--force] [--noude
vsync] {OldLogicalVolume{Name|Path} NewLogicalVolume{Name|Path} | Vol
umeGroupName OldLogicalVolumeName NewLogicalVolumeName}
```

I've formatted it exactly as I see it in my terminal.

How do you go from the command spec above to

```
lvrename /dev/vg2/lv2 /dev/vg2/lvm02
```

Comment: The suggested duplicate only covers square brackets, which doesn't explain the command the OP is interested in.

Answer (score 3):

This is fairly standard manpage syntax. As indicated in [How to read this tcpdump man page?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214482/how-to-read-this-tcpdump-man-page), (square) brackets indicate optional items: thus `-A|--autobackup {y|n}` is optional (as are all the options introduced by hyphens in this instance). Within an item, `|` indicates an alternative: so here, you use either `-A` or `--autobackup`. Finally, `{}` indicates a group: you'd follow `-A` or `--autobackup` with either `y` or `n`.

In `lvrename /dev/vg2/lv2 /dev/vg2/lvm02`, there are no options, so let's ignore all those:

```
lvrename {OldLogicalVolume{Name|Path} NewLogicalVolume{Name|Path} | Vol
umeGroupName OldLogicalVolumeName NewLogicalVolumeName}
```

Reformatted, that's

```
lvrename {OldLogicalVolume{Name|Path} NewLogicalVolume{Name|Path} |
VolumeGroupName OldLogicalVolumeName NewLogicalVolumeName}
```

There's an alternative here: either `OldLogicalVolume{Name|Path} NewLogicalVolume{Name|Path}`, or `VolumeGroupName OldLogicalVolumeName NewLogicalVolumeName`. The form you have only uses two arguments, which means it's the first one: `OldLogicalVolume{Name|Path} NewLogicalVolume{Name|Path}`. Your form uses paths, so that becomes `OldLogicalVolumePath NewLogicalVolumePath`.

Thus you can understand

```
lvrename /dev/vg2/lv2 /dev/vg2/lvm02
```

as matching

```
lvrename OldLogicalVolumePath NewLogicalVolumePath
```

Applying the full decoder ring,

```
lvrename [-A|--autobackup {y|n}] [-d|--debug] 
[-h|--help] [-t|--test] [-v|--verbose] [--version] [-f|--force] [--noude
vsync] {OldLogicalVolume{Name|Path} NewLogicalVolume{Name|Path} | Vol
umeGroupName OldLogicalVolumeName NewLogicalVolumeName}
```

should be read as

```
lvrename [-A|--autobackup {y|n}] [-d|--debug] 
[-h|--help] [-t|--test] [-v|--verbose] [--version] [-f|--force] 
[--noudevsync] {OldLogicalVolume{Name|Path} NewLogicalVolume{Name|Path} |
VolumeGroupName OldLogicalVolumeName NewLogicalVolumeName}
```

and interpreted thus:

- `lvrename` followed by
- optionally, either `-A` or `--autobackup`, followed by either `y` or `n`
- optionally, either `-d` or `--debug`
- optionally, either `-h` or `--help`
- optionally, either `-t` or `--test`
- optionally, either `-v` or `--verbose`
- optionally, `--version`
- optionally, either `-f` or `--force`
- optionally, `--noudevsync`
- finally, one of

  - `OldLogicalVolumeName` (replaced by the actual old logical volume name), followed by `NewLogicalVolumeName` (replaced the actual new logical volume name)
  - `OldLogicalVolumeName` (replaced by the actual old logical volume name), followed by `NewLogicalVolumePath` (replaced the actual new logical volume path)
  - `OldLogicalVolumePath` (replaced by the actual old logical volume path), followed by `NewLogicalVolumeName` (replaced the actual new logical volume name)
  - `OldLogicalVolumePath` (replaced by the actual old logical volume path), followed by `NewLogicalVolumePath` (replaced the actual new logical volume path)
  - `VolumeGroupName` (replaced by the actual volume group name), followed by `OldLogicalVolumeName`, followed by `NewLogicalVolumeName`

Some options only make sense on their own (`--help` and `--version`); in traditional manpages these would appear in their own synopsis.

Comment: Thank for confirming that @roaima, I've updated my answer accordingly.